# Slow image loading R using EBImage

Tags: image, r, matlab, image-processing, imagemagick

Why is it much slower to load in a large image (~4MB) in R using the EBImage package, compared to matlab? is there anyway around this?

**Note:** I'm pretty sure EBImage is in some way a wrapper for imagemagick in R

in R:

```
system.time(im <- readImage("~/Desktop/image.jpg"))
Elapsed time is 10.935 seconds.
```

in Matlab:

```
tic; 
im = imread('~/Desktop/image.jpg');
toc;
Elapsed time is 0.555381 seconds.
```

---

using the raster package

```
system.time(im <- brick('image.jpg'))
```

takes 0.264 seconds

When trying to get the values

```
system.time(vals <- getValues(im))
```

takes 8.617 seconds
so I'm back to square one since I need to extract a channel

---

**Edit 2**

I ended up using the package `jpeg` which has function `readJPEG` and performs better than anything i've tried out there.

```
 system.time(x<-readJPEG('~/Desktop/image.jpg'))
```

Takes about 1.431 seconds for a 4mb image and returns a `n x m x 3` matrix with each layer of the matrix being a color channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it's slow, but try using `raster` instead. You can plot the results of reading it in with `image`

```
require( raster )
im <- brick("~/Desktop/image.jpg")
image( im , y = 1 )

# Or for a rgb coloured image...
plotRGB( im , r=1 , g = 2 , b = 3 )

# To extract values of each layer
vals <- getValues( im )

# A quicker way to get the values would be to use the as.matrix method for rasters
vals <- as.matrix( im )
```

Raster might give you a warning about georeferencing, but it should work and it should be pretty darn quick.

Comment: Oh wow! Spectacular. How do I get the image as a 3 dimensional matrix from a RasterLayer object?

Comment: Use `getValues( im )` , which will return each layer as a column of values in a 2D matrix, with the number of rows equal to `ncol(im) * nrow(im)`. You can take this column and dim it according to your needs.

Comment: Might be a little out the scope of this question, but when you use image(im) to display the image, it comes up looking orange-red ish. Is there anyway to make it display the image as is?

Comment: see ?as.array in raster, but you probably need to read it as brick("image.jpg") to get them all, and then see ?rasterImage (if you want the underlying tools used by raster)

Comment: @mdsumner whoops. My code refers to reading the raster as a brick (as you should for a single file with multiple bands). I was sloppy not updating my code.

Comment: getValues takes so long.. is there any way around this? see edit

Comment: @by0 You can use `as.matrix` - see my code edit. I am not sure how big your rasters are. It's probably not going to work with very big rasters, but should be really fast. It might be more helpful if you tell us what you *want to do* with the matrix of values. There are built-in methods in raster which might be faster depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Still takes ~9.145 seconds with as matrix. I've found another solution. I'll edit my question